# mod_rewrite pretty urls not working

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL:

`http://example.com/gallery/thumb.php?h=400&w=300&a=c&src=Img_0.jpg`

Which I'm trying to use `mod_rewrite` to make "pretty".

The desired URL is:

`http://example.com/h/400/w/300/a/c/src/Img_0.jpg`

And my `mod_rewrite` is:

`RewriteRule ^h/(*)/w/(*)/a/(*)/src/(*)$ /gallery/thumb.php?h=$1&w=$2&a=$3&src=$4 [L]`

But I'm getting a `500 Internal Server Error` error which tells me I've written this rule wrong.

What did I write wrong about it?

**EDIT:** Not a duplicate. My question is pertaining to a particular code that I tried to write myself and did not manage to write a working code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: The question linked contains information about how to turn on rewrite debugging. Use that.

Comment: Maybe just terminology, but you don't `use mod_rewrite to make "pretty"` -   you make the URLs "pretty" in your application _first_. You then use mod_rewrite to turn (ie. _internally rewrite_) the "pretty" URL back into the (real) "ugly" URL (which is what you are doing above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid in your regular expression: `(*)`.

`*` denotes a **repetition** of the previous character. Since you don't have any character in the group there is nothing to repeat.

If you change `(*)` to `(.*)` the expression becomes valid. `.` denotes "every character", so you might want to restrict that a little further.

An expression for your example could be:

```
RewriteRule ^h/(\d+)/w/(\d+)/a/([a-z]+)/src/(.+)$ /gallery/thumb.php?h=$1&w=$2&a=$3&src=$4 [L]
```

Where `\d` denotes a digit and `[a-z]` any character in this range. I also changed `*` to `+`, which matches on "1 or more characters", instead of "0 or more", which would be the `*`.

Comment: Works like a charm and thank you for the explanation. It helped me understand a bit on what's going on.